# jQuery Validation - adding dynamically new rules if new elements are added?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Suppose I have something like this:

[image]

```
<input type="text" class="..." placeholder="Title" name="box[0][title]" value="">
<input type="text" class="..." placeholder="Description" name="box[0][descrip]" value="">
```

If a second 'box' was added it would be:

```
 <input type="text" class="..." placeholder="Title" name="box[1][title]" value="">
 <input type="text" class="..." placeholder="Description" name="box[1][descrip]" value="">
```

How can I add validation if more boxes are added?

```
jQuery('form').validate({


          rules: {
               'box[0][title]': {
                       required: true
                         },
              'box[0][descrip]': {
                       required: true
                         },
                    //How can I add rules if a second box is added?
```

Comment: I haven't used jquery validate, but it may be worth trying to call the validate method again on the form, with the rules + new ones (so keep your rules object as a variable, adding to it with your on add click).

Comment: See [the `.rules()` methods in the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Comment: So on DOM change or after a time interval call jQuery('form').validate({ again?

Comment: No, you cannot call `.validate()` more than once... does not work.  All subsequent calls are ignored.  That's why developer gives you `.rules()` method.

Comment: Depending on the rules, you could simply include the appropriate class or HTML5 attribute.  If you only want `required`, then adding `class="required"` or `required="required"` attribute to the new elements' markup would also work.